# When we get past beta, will I keep my privileges?

Tags: support

I have worked hard on this site. And, I have been rewarded with lot's of permissions. Will I be able to keep those when we leave beta, or will I have to work to re-earn these rewards?

Comment: How long have you been here now? :P

Comment: @jivings less than a month :) my year goal is to beat your reputation!

Answer (score -1):

## Yes

The point of having a beta is to build up a community that can maintain the site. To do that we need people who have a high reputation. That way these people can approve edits, close questions, etc. after the site is graduated.

So yes, you'll be able to keep all your privileges. We need you to have them so you can help us help you have them help us... (?)

**NOTE** Tshepang asked if your privileges get grandfathered in after a site graduates (if this was what you meant, sorry.) The answer is no. So if you have 1k reputation and the ability to edit questions, and the site graduates. You'll need to reach 2k reputation before regaining the ability to edit questions.

Comment: Say Beta requires 1k rep to edit Questions, and the site graduates before user reaches 2k. Will said 1k user be able to edit without approval?

Comment: @Tshepang I've addressed that in my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Answer starts with a big fat **Yes** and in the last line actually says that yes means no.

Comment: That is a bit of a rip... and will happen to me on SE Arduino when it finally graduates from Beta... :-(